# Top Users (and Chatters) in Puzzling SE, Suggested For NEW USERS

Tags: logical-deduction

Ciphers, anagrams, and crossword-like clues of the usernames of our top Puzzling SE users (or) frequent Puzzling SE users. Should be fairly simple, so therefore, new users (can get easy rep and meet our community's moderators and top puzzlers. 
(Not recomended for older users to give opputunities to newer users, but if you feel you are new enough, feel free to try it)

> 1. Devious
> 2. Our favorite British user! "Welcome to the Riddler's Den!".
> 3. Manages to be a (Diet) Coke drinking canine.
> 4. Gandalf!
> 5. rot19{Tevhgct}.
> 6. A computer software that gained artificial intelligence and now happens to be a coder.
> 7. Brazilian anime.
> 8. Key word 10K, Ih xc mz uz qn eg pb nk bp uz uk dl qn qp et eh la le en kl la bp ry?
> 9. Beyblade, Beyblade, let it rip!
> 10. A gag at churchmen.
> 11. A shower of colors.
> 12. Never Leaving 600-20-8

Comment: My apologies that I couldn't get everbody

Comment: Please dont start ranting about how you wernt on the list other top users not on this list

Comment: Ha ha, nice one. :-)

Comment: I've slightly reworded your first sentence, I hope that's alright and better captures what you wanted to convey. Also a few bits of formatting changes.

Comment: ...what? Really? You had to go for that?

Comment: If I've been here longer than 45 days (mostly lurking), but with rep < 250, can I still answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, eight months seems too long for me....

Comment: @North sad, this is one of the few puzzles I can actually solve in Puzzling.SE haha

Comment: Downvoted because of the arbitrary restriction on who is "allowed" to answer.

Comment: So tempted to edit "favorite" to "favourite".

Comment: I dont know whose to accept.

Comment: woah i'm part of this puzzle

Comment: You *were* technically the first authentic user I met

Comment: @Randal'Thor yes it’s terrible oof

Comment: tg he hz nq cm wt eg ap no mx - [ze uk cc ec ke zm kn gk an le en xd ne uh le kp la ig ah ct sd lq pk](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/559/week/puzzling/2017-10-01)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Devious

> [@Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi) (Anagram of Devious)

2) Our favorite British user! "Welcome to the Riddler's Den!". (With the help of @Hosea)

> [@Rand al'Thor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor)

3) Manages to be a (Diet) Coke drinking canine.

> [@rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/30633/rubio) (Profile picture is literally a diet coke

4) Gandalf!

> <s>[@frodoskywalker](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/3987/frodoskywalker)</s> [@Mithrandir](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/25966/mithrandir)

5) rot19{Tevhgct}. (With the help of @Hosea)

> [@Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208/alconja)

6) A computer software that gained artificial intelligence and now happens to be a coder.

> [@thecoder16](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/36976/thecoder16) (His profile even says "hi, i'm a person.")

7) Brazillian Anime

> [@ffao](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20521/ffao) (The user is from Brazil and his profile picture is from an anime)

8) Key word 10K, Ih xc mz uz qn eg pb nk bp uz uk dl qn qp et eh la le en kl la bp ry?

> [@Bass](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/36023/bass)

9) Beyblade, Beyblade, let it rip! (With the help of @Jordan.J.D)

> [@sid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/23009/sid) Profile picture is from a character of beyblade

10) A gag at churchmen. (With the help of @Hosea)

> [@Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19114/gareth-mccaughan) Anagram of "A gag at churchmen"

11) A shower of colors (With the help of @Hosea)

> <s>[@PeterTaylor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/228/peter-taylor)</s> [@GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421/gentlepurplerain)

12) Never Leaving 600-20-8 (With the help of @Hosea)

> [@NL628](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/43256/nl628)

Comment: 2 is Rand al'Thor. 5 is Alconja

Comment: 9 is sid - https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZitJa-DxWrn7NQhTGJakkZqOJ-RJid-P0c_1CldSH3rVlUoTIOloo0o08waSB7CnoGjcZB9XMXo4ugC7m7ODQ1Jejbf8JjJQQ5cafJ97QsC0UnrqMWzljJpjy0a-XBB0NSWTEpIzOmlPV6qaKT11LpxoLviJBrAW_13owOxBaLUwfUIqyv9jeTt2HDPXWc_1ZZ4fqBJYo37cCLTS-kZBfv3N7eX55q5vuUlB-HvufGdsHX6tZ7dqno4fNp3xhw-G2LWFS7oTXw2ps0lcVCKrmh0i9KzmMo3TulPJ9t6gG2cEoxZf_1TQb6syicLZTa9zWoJF1RmrVkxfUHHCvVi7d5nTb_1tAxYdZ5w

Comment: google rot13 and you should be set on 5.  12 isn't too hard either, don't overthink it.

Comment: I think 10 is anagram of Gareth McCaughan.

Comment: I'm also guessing 12 is NL628.

Comment: 11 is GentlePurpleRain.

Comment: Well done @Hosea!

Comment: I did a double take when I saw my name. Thank you for the compliment.

Answer (score 8):

1. Devious

   > Deusovi (anagram?)
2. Our favourite British user!

   > Rand Al'Thor i think it's spelled? Sphinx's Lair
3. Manages to be a (Diet) Coke drinking canine.

   > Rubio (profile pic and search haha)
4. Gandalf!

   > Mithrandir
5. rot19{Tevhgct}

   > Alconja?
6. A computer software that gained artificial intelligence and now happens to be a coder.

   > thecoder16?
7. Brazilian Anime

   > ffao (thanks Gabriel)
8. Key word 10k

   > Bass (congrats)
9. Beyblade, beyblade, let it rip!

   > Sid
10. A gag at churchmen

    > Gareth McCaughan
11. A shower of colours

    > GentlePurpleRain (thanks Hosea)
12. Never leaving 600-20-8

    > NL628